# Missing file error when running a program in Alpine Docker container

Tags: docker

I have the following Dockerfile...

```
FROM gliderlabs/alpine

WORKDIR /go/src/app

ADD menu-api menu-api

ENTRYPOINT ["menu-api"]
CMD ["menu-api"]
```

If I build my go binary using `$ GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 CGO_ENABLED=0 go build` then build my Docker image `$ docker build -t menu-api .`

Then attempt to run my Docker image using `$ docker run menu-api`. I get the following error:

`container_linux.go:262: starting container process caused "exec: \"menu-api\": executable file not found in $PATH"
docker: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:262: starting container process caused "exec: \"menu-api\": executable file not found in $PATH".
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled`

Comment: Please accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, I needed to do...

```
CMD ["./menu-api"]
```

Instead of...

```
CMD ["menu-api"]
```

Comment: Alternatively you could add your WORKDIR to PATH.